# PHP: What is the searching algorithm implemented in array_search()?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, search

I have an array of items on which I would like to apply search function. I am considering sorting the array and simply applying binary search for now as it need not be too complex, however if I run into problems I'll try other methods.

My question is; what is the search algorithm used in the array_search()? If it is indeed binary search I can use that.

Comment: I'd say linear search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP performs a linear search - [here's the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a98fd7125ac9165822fa34a01e35a97a2076c3b9/ext/standard/array.c#L1235)

Answer (score 3):

It has to be sequential search, because the array might not be sorted.

If you need to search an array often, use `array_flip` to convert it to an associative array where the values become the keys. Looking up keys in an array is a hash lookup.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a binary search.... it simply loops through the array until it finds the first matching element.... the internal equivalent of

```
foreach($haystack as $key => $value) { 
    if ($value == $needle) { 
        return $key; 
    }
}
```

Though for a fast search alternative, a Trie might be better than a binary search